What should be the contentType for excel files sent as attachment by bot?
`Hi, I am working on a bot where it will post an excel attachment to a Channel. I have the following piece of code for the same:
 const attachment = { 
         contentUrl: {public access enabled blob url}, 
         contentType: "**application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet**", 
         name: "new_excel_blob.xlsx" 
         }; 
   const reply: any = {type: ActivityTypes.Message};
   reply.text = Please find your excel; 
   reply.attachments = [attachment]; 
   await context.sendActivity(reply); 

Above code throws "Unknown attachment type" error. I have also tried content Type: "reference". Getting the same error. If I use the same code for image (content Type: "image/png") then I am able to post image with message to the channel. What should be the correct content Type for excel / .xslx files?
PS: I have tried user attaching an excel and tagging the bot and got the content Type (which is also same as "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet".
Thanks & Regards, Kalyan
Tried "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" and "reference". Both throwing same "Unknown attachment type" error.`

The Excel MIME type (as that's what it's you're looking for) can be application/vnd.ms-excel or application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12 or just plain text/xml. Most likely you'll need that last one. Though application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet is correct for xlsx
